# Не могу настроить почтовый сервер(Postfix/Dovecot с интеграцией в MS Active Directory) на alt linux

Tags: ldap, postfix, windows-server-2012, dovecot, altlinux

Есть домен на Windows Server2012r2(FQDN ad.test.local,ip 192.168.200.1), попытался настроить почтовый сервер на alt linux(ввел в домен, fqdn altmail.test.local, ip 192.168.200.77)  для пользователей из Active Directory, ничего не получается. **Может у кого-то есть решение?**

Прикладываю конфигурационные файлы.

Postfix:

main.cf

```
 # Команда "mailbox_command" в Postfix предназначена для указания команды или
    # скрипта, который будет запущен для доставки электронной почты в почтовый ящик
    #  пользователя.
    # Она используется для настройки доставки электронной почты в файл или
    #  внешнюю программу, которая обрабатывает полученные сообщения.
    #  Например, она может быть использована для доставки почты в файловую систему
    # пользователя, в базу данных или для передачи сообщения другому серверу 
    #электронной почты.
    # Благодаря "mailbox_command" в Postfix можно настроить доставку почты 
    # в пользовательские почтовые программы или в кастомные программы,
    #  которые выполняют определенную обработку полученной почты.
    #  Она обеспечивает гибкость в настройке системы доставки почты и позволяет
    # организовать обработку полученных сообщений в соответствии с требованиями и
    # потребностями системы.
    # Параметр inet_interfaces определяет сетевой интерфейс
    # адреса, на которые эта почтовая система получает почту.
    inet_interfaces = all
    mailbox_command = /usr/libexec/procmail -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
    inet_protocols = all
    # Авторизацию будет проводить Dovecot, поэтому в файле main.cf
    # основных настроек Postfix: Может быть TLS, тогда .cert
    # SSL/TLS
    smtpd_use_tls = yes
    smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
    smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    smtpd_sasl_local_domain = test.local
    smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
    smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
    #mbox, mlist
    smtpd_sender_login_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/virtual_mlist.conf
    smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
    smtpd_tls_cert_file = /var/lib/ssl/certs/dovecot.cert
    smtpd_tls_key_file = /var/lib/ssl/private/dovecot.key
    smtpd_tls_CAfile = /var/lib/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
    #Параметр myhostname указывает имя интернет-хоста этой почтовой системы.
    #По умолчанию используется полное доменное имя из gethostname().
    myhostname = altmail.test.local
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias.conf
    alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mbox.conf
    # Домен нашего сервера
    # По умолчанию выделяется из имени хоста отбрасыванием первой части, поэтому вручную указывать обычно не нужно
    mydomain = test.local
    # Домен, с которого отправляется локальная почта.
    myorigin = test.local
    # Домены, для которых данный сервер является конечной точкой доставки почты.
    # Обычно лучше почтовые домены обслуживать через механизм virtual, поэтому в этом параметре
    # чаще всего стоит лишь указать localhost и имя хоста, так, на всякий случай,
    # можно вообще оставить значение пустым.
    mydestination = localhost, $myhostname, localhsot.$mydomain
    #Доступ во вне не надо, поэтому нет значения
    relayhost =
    #параметр mynetworks определяет список "доверенных" SMTP клиентов
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.200.0/24
    # Параметр recipient_delimiter определяет разделитель между
    # именами пользователей и расширениями адресов
    recipient_delimiter = +
    #unknown_local_recipient_reject_code указывает код ответа SMTP-сервера, когда домен получателя соответствует 
    #mydestination или ${proxy,inet}_interfaces, в то время как $local_recipient_maps непустой и адрес получателя
    #или локальная часть адреса не найдены. Значение по умолчанию - 550 (отклонять почту),
    unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
    # не надо
    debug_peer_level = 2
    debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1, test.local
    # размер
    message_size_limit = 10240000
    # ---------------------- VIRTUAL DOMAINS START ----------------------
    virtual_transport = dovecot
    virtual_mailbox_base            = /srv/admin
    virtual_mailbox_domains         = $mydomain
    # Указываем на конфиг, в котором описано как получить данные о почтовом яшике
    virtual_mailbox_maps            = ldap:/etc/postfix/virtual_mlist.conf
    # Указываем на конфиги, в которых описан способ получения данных о псевдонимах почтовых ящиков и о списках рассылки
    virtual_alias_maps              = ldap:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias.conf, ldap:/etc/postfix/virtual_mlist.conf
    #не надо
    virtual_minimum_uid     = 150
    # Идентификатор локального пользователя на alt linux admin
    virtual_uid_maps                = static:500
    virtual_gid_maps                = static:500
    virtual_transport               = dovecot
    dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
    # ---------------------- VIRTUAL DOMAINS END ----------------------
    #запрет на отправку и прием почты на все домена, за исключением test.local
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access, reject
    smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access, reject
```

master.cf

```
    pickup    fifo  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
    cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
    qmgr      fifo  n       -       y       300     1       qmgr
    tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
    rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
    bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
    defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
    trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
    verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
    flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
    proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
    proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
    smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
    relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
            -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
    showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
    error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
    retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
    discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
    local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
    virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
    lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
    anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
    scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
    postlog   unix-dgram n  -       y       -       1       postlogd


    filter    unix  -   n   n   -   10  pipe
        flags=Rq user=_filter argv=content-filter -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
  
    ***Добавил только***
    # Dovecot LDA, описание транспорта, admin - локальный пользователь all linux
    dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      flags=DRhu user=admin:admin argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
    smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

virtual_mbox.conf

```
# Адрес LDAP-сервера, или  имя
server_host = ldap://192.168.200.1

# Где искать пользователей
search_base = ou=Отдел цифровой трансформации,ou=Управление,dc=test,dc=local
version = 3

# По какому полю идентифицируем пользователей
query_filter = (&(objectclass=person)(userPrincipalName=%s))
result_attribute = userPrincipalName
#ldap_user@test.local -пользователь, через которого осуществляется поиск 
result_format = %u/
bind_dn = ldap_user@test.local
bind_pw = Password@12
cache = no
```

virtual_alias.conf

```
version = 3
server_host = ldap://192.168.200.1
search_base = ou=Отдел цифровой трансформации,ou=Управление,dc=test,dc=local
timeout = 3

# Поле, в котором будем искать почтовые псевдонимы. Используется mail, т.к. оно доступно через редактирование свойств пользователя


query_filter = (mail=%s)

result_filter = %s
result_attribute = userPrincipalName
special_result_attribute = member
scope = sub
bind = yes
bind_dn = ldap_user@test.local
bind_pw = Password@12
```

virtual_mlist.conf

```
version = 3
server_host = ldap://192.168.200.1
search_base = ou=Отдел цифровой трансформации,ou=Управление,dc=test,dc=local
timeout = 3

# Запрашиваем группы распространения(специальный тип групп в AD), отфильтровываем мы их с помощью sAMAccountType=268435457, посмотреть номер
# любого объекта можно также через ADSI edit, у групп распространения он соответствует 268435457

query_filter = (&(mail=%s)(sAMAccountType=268435457))

result_filter = %s
result_attribute = userPrincipalName
special_result_attribute = member
scope = sub
bind = yes
bind_dn = ldap_user@test.local
bind_pw = Password@12
```

Dovecot:
10-auth.conf

```
auth_mechanisms = plain
!include auth-ldap.conf.ext
```

10-logging.conf

```
#Файл журнала, который будет использоваться для отладочных сообщений.
#По умолчанию используется info_log_path. Будет /var/log/dovecot_debug.log
debug_log_path = /var/log/dovecot_debug.log
# Неудачные попытки аутентификации и причины
auth_verbose = yes
# Более подробное введение журнала
auth_debug = yes
# Несовпадение паролей
auth_debug_passwords = yes
# Причина, по которой не отправляются письма
mail_debug = yes
```

10-mail.conf

```
# mail_location в dovecot отвечает за указание расположения почтовых ящиков пользователей. Этот параметр определяет путь к каталогу, где будут храниться почтовые сообщения и другие связанные с ними файлы для каждого пользователя.
# Это может быть локальный путь на сервере или удаленный путь (например, через протоколы POP3 или IMAP).
# Кроме того, mail_location может определять формат и структуру файловой системы для хранения почты, например, в виде отдельных файлов или в виде директорий с различными типами файлов.
mail_location = maildir:/srv/admin/%u 
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
}
# для доступа к почте (локальный admin)
mail_uid = 500
mail_gid = 500

protocol !indexer-worker {
}

mbox_write_locks = fcntl
```

15-lda.conf

```
# Local Delivery Agent - через этот механизм postfix будет контактировать с dovecot.
protocol lda {
# mail_plugin_dir: Параметр mail_plugin_dir указывает директорию,
# в которой хранятся плагины для почтового сервера Postfix. 
# Плагины могут использоваться для добавления дополнительной функциональности,
# обработки сообщений или применения дополнительных проверок без изменения 
# исходного кода Postfix.
# postmaster_address: Параметр postmaster_address определяет адрес электронной 
# почты, на который будут отправляться оповещения и отчеты об ошибках,
# связанных с Postfix. Почтовый администратор, ответственный за управление 
# сервером, должен указать адрес электронной почты, на котором он получит 
# эти сообщения.
# sendmail_path: Параметр sendmail_path задает полный путь к исполняемому
#  файлу sendmail, используемому в Postfix. 
# Sendmail - это интерфейсный синтаксис для доставки почтовых сообщений, 
# и Postfix может использовать его для доставки сообщений или ретрансляции 
# их в другой MTA (Mail Transfer Agent).
    hostname = altmail.test.local
# Возможно эти две строчки(кроме postmaster_address) надо убрать
    mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules
    postmaster_address = ldap_user@test.local
    sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
}
```

auth-ldap.conf.ext

```
passdb {
  driver = ldap
  # Путь к файлу конфигурации LDAP, 
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
}
userdb {
  driver = ldap
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
  # Default fields can be used to specify defaults that LDAP may override
  default_fields = home=/srv/admin/%u uid=500 gid=500
}
```

dovecot-ldap.conf.ext

```
# Задаем адрес нашего DC, 
uris = ldap://192.168.200.1

# Путь к пользователю, с помощью которого будем подключаться к AD для получения
# необходимой информации.
# Пользователя в AD нужно создать заранее.
dn = cn=ldap_user,ou=ANY,dc=test,dc=local

# Пароль этого пользователя.
dnpass = Password@12

# Использовать ли защищенное соединение
tls = no

# Подключаться к AD
auth_bind = yes

# Формат имени пользователя
auth_bind_userdn = %n@test.local

# Версия протокола
ldap_version = 3

# Где искать пользователей, можно указать самый корень домена, тогда поиск будет выполняться во
# всех подразделениях.  Корень домена не работает.
base = ou=Отдел цифровой трансформации,ou=Управление,dc=test,dc=local

deref = searching

scope = subtree

# Фильтрация пользователей. Также указываем по чему будем идентифицировать их. Если домен AD и
# почтовый домен совпадают - проще всего по userPrincipalName, оно точно уникальное.
user_filter = (&(objectClass=person)(userPrincipalName=%u))
pass_filter = (&(ObjectClass=person)(userPrincipalName=%u))
```

Comment: Логи: Nov 20 08:57:23 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot/modules/auth
Nov 20 08:57:23 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/modules/auth/lib20_auth_var_expand_crypt.so
Nov 20 08:57:23 auth: Debug: Read auth token secret from /var/run/dovecot/auth-token-secret.dat
Nov 20 08:57:23 auth: Debug: ldap(/etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext): LDAP initialization took 0 msecs
Nov 20 08:57:48 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=11462)
Nov 20 08:57:48 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=11463)